# Добавление поддержки команд консоли Symfony 3 в PHPStrom

Tags: phpstorm, symfony

При попытке добавления Symfony Command Line Tool в PHPStorm программа выдает такую ошибку:

> Problem
>   Failed to determine version.
>   Command
>   C:\Program Files\XAMPP\php\php.exe F:\sites\www\symfony_test\bin\console -V
>   Output
>   Symfony version 3.0.2 - app/dev/debug

Порядок действий в PhpStorm:

1. File->Settings->Command Line Tools -> Add Symfony Command Line Tool
2. Выбираю путь к php.exe
3. Выбираю путь к файлу console (path_to_project\bin\console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо ждать обновления от PHPStorm'а, но если вам крайне необходимо, то можно создать `Custom Tool` в `Command Line Tool Support` а потом заполнить его конфиг. [Пример](https://gist.github.com/maartenba/5063217).

Так же вы можете написать небольшую тулзу, которая сможет транслировать данные из `php bin/console list --format=xml` (так же по аналогии берется список команд для консоли Symfony2) в формат для PHPStorm'а

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<framework xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/frameworkDescriptionVersion1.1.3.xsd" name="azure" invoke="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\CLI\0.6.9\wbin\azure.cmd" alias="azure" enabled="true" version="2">
    <help><![CDATA[Windows Azure: Microsoft's Cloud Platform]]></help>
    <command>
        <name>help</name>
        <params>command</params>
        <help>Display help for a givencommand</help>
    </command>
    <command>
        <name>portal</name>
        <params>options</params>
        <help>Opens the portal in a browser</help>
    </command>
<!-- ... -->
</framework>
```